# cannot create second table in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I was newbie in using sqlite database android. and now I have a problem with my sqlite database in android,
first i create first table :

```
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MASTER = "create table"
        + TABLE_MASTER + " (" + MASTER_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAMA_MASALAH
        + " Integer not null, " + JLH_KRITERIA + " Integer not null, "
        + JLH_ALTERNATIVE + " text not null);";
```

it wass success, but when i create the second table :

```
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_KRITERIA = "create table if not exist "
    +TABLE_KRITERIA+ "("+ KRITERIA_ID
    + "integer primary key autoincrement, " 
    +KRITERIA_NAMA+ "text);";
```

but it was error, and in the LogCat it said :

> No such table: tableKriteria: while compiling: select idKriteria, namaKriteria From tableKriteria

here the full code of my SQLiteAdapter.java :

```
package com.MFrameworkAHP;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class SQLiteAdapter {
public static final String NAMA_DATABASE = "MY_DATABASE";
public static final String TABLE_MASTER = "MY_TABLE";
public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String MASTER_ID = "_id";
public static final String NAMA_MASALAH = "Content1";
public static final String JLH_KRITERIA = "Content2";
public static final String JLH_ALTERNATIVE = "Content3";

public static final String TABLE_KRITERIA = "tableKriteria";
public static final String KRITERIA_ID= "idKriteria";
public static final String KRITERIA_NAMA = "namaKriteria";
public static final String KRITERIA_IDDATA = "idDataKriteria";


// create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MASTER = "create table"
        + TABLE_MASTER + " (" + MASTER_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAMA_MASALAH
        + " Integer not null, " + JLH_KRITERIA + " Integer not null, "
        + JLH_ALTERNATIVE + " text not null);";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_KRITERIA = "create table if not exist "
    +TABLE_KRITERIA+ "("+ KRITERIA_ID
    + "integer primary key autoincrement, " 
    +KRITERIA_NAMA+ "text);";

;
//private static final String

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private Context context;

public SQLiteAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, NAMA_DATABASE, null,
            MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, NAMA_DATABASE, null,
            MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    sqLiteHelper.close();
}

public long insert(String namaMasalah, String jlhKriteria, String jlhAlternative) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NAMA_MASALAH, namaMasalah);
    contentValues.put(JLH_KRITERIA, jlhKriteria);
    contentValues.put(JLH_ALTERNATIVE, jlhAlternative);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_MASTER, null, contentValues);
}

public long insertKriteria(String namaKriteria){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    //cv.put(KRITERIA_ID, idKriteria);
    cv.put(KRITERIA_NAMA,namaKriteria);

    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_KRITERIA, null, cv);
}
public int deleteAll() {
    return  sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_MASTER, null, null);

}

public void delete_byID(int id) {
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_MASTER, MASTER_ID + "=" + id, null);
}

public void update_byID(int id, String v1, String v2, String v3) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NAMA_MASALAH, v1);
    values.put(JLH_KRITERIA, v2);
    values.put(JLH_ALTERNATIVE, v3);
    sqLiteDatabase
            .update(TABLE_MASTER, values, MASTER_ID + "=" + id, null);
}

public Cursor queueAll() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { MASTER_ID, NAMA_MASALAH, JLH_KRITERIA,
            JLH_ALTERNATIVE };
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_MASTER, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor queueKriteria() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KRITERIA_ID, KRITERIA_NAMA };
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_KRITERIA, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor queueAll_SortBy_namaMasalah() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { MASTER_ID, NAMA_MASALAH, JLH_KRITERIA,
            JLH_ALTERNATIVE };
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_MASTER, columns, null,
            null, null, null, NAMA_MASALAH);

    return cursor;
}

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_KRITERIA);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MASTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

}

I had tried all about one weeks to solve my problems, like changed the database version, changed the create statement for the second table, etc. but it didn't work :(
there are many question in this forum as same with my question, but it couldn't solve my problem, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158029/unable-to-create-second-table-in-sqlite), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829010/problem-when-creating-second-table-in-sqlite) , etc.

guys, please help me,. .

thanks before .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you might need to add some spaces to the 'create' string. Also it should be `exists` and not `exist`. Try...

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_KRITERIA = "create table if not exists "
+TABLE_KRITERIA+ " ("+ KRITERIA_ID
+ " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
+KRITERIA_NAMA+ " text);";
```

Comment: thanks, i have done it, but still didn't work. still the same error.

Comment: @JonasMFBanurea : You do realise that the `onCreate` method of `SQLiteOpenHelper` is only ever called once (if the database doesn't exist)? If the database has already been created then `onCreate` will never be called again. You will need to delete the database and then run your code again.

Comment: i had tried it, even i had change the database version, clear data and uninstall the app from my device. But it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you code is still the same, then your first `create table` is missing a space.

you have

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MASTER = "create table"
```

and it should be

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MASTER = "create table "
```

Also, could you post your error message?

In the onUpgrade() you should perform an upgrade.  The quickest is to drop the tables and then recreated.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.i("MFrameworkAHP", "Upgrading database to " + newVersion);
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_KRITERIA);
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_MASTER);
    onCreate(db);
}

   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.i("MFrameworkAHP", CREATE_TABLE_KRITERIA);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_KRITERIA);

        Log.i("MFrameworkAHP", CREATE_TABLE_MASTER);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MASTER);
    }
```

That will delete everything on an upgrade which is not ideal, but at least it will recreate the tables in your testing when you change the database version.

Comment: here was the error :  No such table: tableKriteria: while compiling: select idKriteria, namaKriteria From tableKriteria.


tableKriteria was not created.

Comment: and you are sure that you are incrementing the database version after you made the change?  Also try logging out the complete create statements in the `onCreate()` so that they get logged and you can verify that the code is being run.  Also, the `onUpgrade()` should do something, either drop all tables and then run `onCreate()` or do some sort of update.  When the increment that database version, it will call `onUpgrade()` and not `onCreate()`.  For now I would issue `drop table` statements in the `onUpgrade` and then call `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now and the solution is to create all tables from the beggining. If you create a database with just one table for testing and later you try to create the rest of the tables it won't work. So define a new database name and create all the tables you're gonna need at once, that should be enough.